# The right database structure and model relations in CakePHP for my project (small shop)?

Tags: php, cakephp, database-design

I have a pretty simple shop-system. I'm working with CakePHP. Actually I wouldn't call it shop, it's rather a basic form where you can type in your data and which items in which color you want and that's it.
There is one buying-form which is "open to the public" and then there are buying-forms which are password secured.
The latter ones have a selection of the items (or selection of colors) which you get on the public site, but have discounts.
I want to save the orders in a database. I have a table orders and ordered_products. That's working fine.
It works pretty good, but only because I made something not very good: Since there are just a few products I just wrote an array in the controller with the names, prices and stuff... the discounts or selection of products I handled by just overwriting the products-property.

Well, putting data in the controller is not really the idea behind the MVC-Structure, so I was thinking about who to handle the products, the selection of products for the different password-secured buying forms and the discounts with models.

My idea was, to create the following tables:

```
products (id, name, price,...) -hasAndBelongsToMany Color
colors (id, name)
products_colors (product_id, color_id)
```

Now to set in which "closed-area", which products in which color and with which special price can be ordered I thought of the following tables (the actual table and field names are of course not wise chosen, but just for the idea):

```
product_selections (id, closed-area_name, product_id, special_price) hasAndBelongsToMany Color
product_selections_colors (product_selection_id, color_id)
```

When I'm creating the public buying form I would just use the top three tables. but building the "closed-area" I would use the bottom two, selecting the product_ids and special_prices from product_selection as well as the different colors over the product_selections_colors-table for the according "closed-area" (i dont know a better name for that right now...). with the product_id i would get the other information about the product from the table products and create the buying form with this data.

I want to have it all in a database, because then I can better work with the orders (creating receipts, deliverynotes etc.).

I would like to know what you think about that, because I have the feeling that I'm going totally in the wrong direction, since it feel way to complicated for such a simple thing...
I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I would recommend doing it this way:

Have a users table with a field for "group_id". This allows you to have multiple users with login privileges that all can view the same options or colors based on their grouping.

In the case of a general (non-logged in) user, the assign the group_id to default to 0.

Next, ditch the product_selections and product_selections_colors tables.
You don't want to have to repeat products across tables.
Simply add a new table that pairs which product ids can be purchased by which group_ids. (HABTM relationship in cake)

You will obviously need to tweak this general setup to work specifically for your needs.